# Given a list of strings, how would one be able determine whether all the strings are present in a particular paragraph?

Tags: string, full-text-search

For example, if I have a list

```
list = ['brown', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

and two sentences:

```
1) "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
2) "The quick brown fox jumps over the dog."
```

Is there a way to determine that all the strings are present in sentence 1, but not in sentence 2?

Comment: Are you asking for a specific programming language?

Comment: @confetti No, just in general. What would be the quickest way to do this, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

## Bash:

Input is taken from command line as argument, if not all words from the array are present the script will exit with a code of 1 and print a "Not found" message.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sentence=$1
declare -a arr=("brown" "lazy" "dog")

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ $sentence != *"$i"* ]]; then
        echo "Not found"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

## PHP:

Same concept, prints "Not found" if not all array contents are present in the `$sentence` string.

```php
$words = array("brown", "lazy", "dog");
$sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
foreach($words as $word){
    if(strpos($sentence, $word) === false){
        echo "Not found";
    }
}
```

## Python:

```py
words = ["brown", "lazy", "dog"]
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
for word in words:
    if word not in sentence:
        print "Not found"
```

## Ruby:

```rb
array = ["brown", "lazy", "dog"]
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the dog."
array.each { |word| sentence.include?(word) ? () : (puts 'Not found') }
```